# TextOverFlow.ellipsis in Widget Text not work

Tags: flutter, dart, text-widget

[image]

my widget text Wrap inside Expanded, row, and Column

```
return Container(
          child: Expanded(
            flex: 9,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                // .......
              },
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 15),
                        child: Container(
                          width: 2,
                          color: Color(0XFF2B9FDC),
                        )),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text( item.name,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            maxLines: 2,
                          ),
                          Text(item.catgeory),
                          Text(item.price,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
```

I got error :  Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 7.3 pixels on the right.

AnyOne can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap your `container` with `Expanded` and use flex property as per your design and let me know its working or not

```
 return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            // .......
          },
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 15),
                    child: Container(
                      width: 2,
                      color: Color(0XFF2B9FDC),
                    )),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text( item.name,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        maxLines: 2,
                      ),
                      Text(item.catgeory),
                      Text(item.price,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: thanks...I wrap Padding with Expanded, and its work

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
Text(
        item.name,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        maxLines: 2,
        ),
```

into this:

```
Text(
        item.name,
        softWrap : true,
        maxLines: 2,
        ),
```

> softWrap → bool
>
> Whether the text should break at soft line breaks

Comment: thanks... i have tried, but still not work brother, i wrap the widget text inside expanded, row, and column

Comment: did u remove overflow?